# How do I click on highlighted option in selenium webdriver c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am working with select2 element. I open the option bar by clicking on the arrow, then enter text to filter the options to only one and then I dont know how to click on that option, so It could be selected, any ideas?

```
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='s2id_testid']/a/span[2]/b")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#select2-drop input.select2-input")).SendKeys("54");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can harness the power of the driver as you have already done with the `FindElement` function. Instead of using `By.XPath` or `By.CssSelector` use, `By.Id` and simply ensure that the `select2` element `option` that you're trying to click has an id.  If it doesn't have one, make sure that you have one assigned in your markup or that a predictable one is generated when your HTML is rendered.

```
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("myKnownId")).Click();
```

Often I try using the selenium feature as a means for extensibility.  For example, you can use the following to check if an element with a given identifier is either visible or not visible.

```
    [Then(@"An element with the identifier (.*) is (visible|not visible)")]
    public void ThenAnElementWithTheIdentifierIsVisible(string identifier, string visibility)
    {
        if (visibility.Equals("visible"))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting to wait for element with identifier {0} to be visible.", identifier));
            Driver.WaitUntil(d => d.FindElement(By.Id(identifier))
                                   .Displayed);

        }
        else if (visibility.Equals("not visible"))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting to wait for element with identifier {0} to not be visible.", identifier));
            Driver.WaitUntil(d => !d.FindElement(By.Id(identifier))
                                    .Displayed);
        }
    }
```

This allows for re-use and you can easily see how powerful this can become as you build out your UI testing.

Comment: It has an Id, but when I try to use 
`driver.FindElement(By.Id("select2-text")).Click();`
webdriver selects the first option, but not the highlighted one, maybe I somehow I can tell it to click text that contains id (54) of that option?

Comment: Can you add the rendered HTML either here in a comment or to the question, I want to ensure that the element id attribute is correctly set.  I have some doubts about "select2-text" being the id.

Comment: proper Id I guess is id="select2-result-label-1529", but when I use it, nothing happens (unable to locate element...)

Comment: Sometimes there needs to be a delay before asking the driver to find the element, and is that id dynamic or static?  How are you ensuring that it is not changing between test executions?  If you noticed in the example snippet, there is actually an extension method that we wrote that waits a certain amount of time before giving up to find the element.  We have found that sometimes elements are not truly ready for a brief moment.

Comment: Im using this to cope with that problem
`driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));`
and Id is dynamic

Comment: We are using that in addition to the explicit waits as we found that method to not be reliable.

Comment: got it working by using xpath to find text when the element is present
`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[.='54']")).Click();`